# Does stolen dark elixir before th 7 count to heroic heist achievment

Tags: clash-of-clans

I've won 800 DE and does it count to heroic heist at town hall 6?

Comment: Why dont you check your achievement list and tell us?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, rest assured that even though you don't have a way to store dark elixir, it will help you get the achievement later on.